Setting up Custom Post Types to appear in Wordpress RSS Feeds
I'm using Wordpress with Elementor and then using Crocoblock JetEngine to create custom post types which I was hoping would be accessible through RSS feeds, but its not quite working, so I'm hoping someone could help me solve this enigma.
Tests and Results
After researching I found that you can access any post type feed by going to /feed/?post_type=<cpt_name> and I have tested this in Feedly, but it only gets the title, date and author.. for the CPT's I have created... no content. (See image below).
[Feedly Test] https://i.sstatic.net/fzGGAeJ6.png
Research
I've read a lot about people creating custom feed URL's using copies of archive.php, but I'm not a developer (hence Elementor) and can't seem to get my head around it.
Example 1 (Basic Feed):
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/add-custom-fields-to-custom-post-type-rss?rq=1
Example 2 (Taxonomy):
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144061/add-taxonomy-values-within-a-custom-post-type-rss-feed?noredirect=1&lq=1
My Theory
My assumption though as to why the basic (default) feeds for the CPT's are not working is because there must be some mapping needed between the meta fields (created in JE when creating the CPT's) and the default WP fields used for the RSS feed.
WP Required Post Fields (?)
I've looked up what I believe are the required fields for any post in WP and it seems to be the following:
Required WP Post Fields
Testing Again
Based on this I then used a form to insert/update a post and tried inserting content into both "Post Content" and "Post Excerpt" and also some tax into "Post Terms" in the hope that this would then appear, but still nothing.
Help
Does any one know where I am going wrong? Or do I need to create new .php files and how and where do you specify specific fields created in the CPT's so they appear correctly.
Thank you in advance.

Hi, a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
